# Remove part of URL using HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, multilingual

I know this is an often asked question, but nothing I found would work for me.

I am trying to remove parts of the url of my little website.

My url structure right now is like this:

www.example.com/en/catalog/categoryName

And I would like to cut out "Catalog" so that it would look like this:

www.example.com/en/categoryName

But nothing I have used seems to work. 
This is my .htaccess file atm.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ $1 [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also I will be getting an url that will look like this:

www.example.com/en/product/productName

And ofcourse I would like to cut "product" of of that, so that it would look like this.

www.example.com/en/productName

Comment: You should really show us what you tried, and describe what result you got with it.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, ok, sorry about that. The code you see above is the code that I have tried. But when I use it or similar codes, nothing happens. I know that the browser sees my htacces because `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` works.

Comment: `^catalog/`, with the leading circumflex, demands that the requested URL starts with `catalog/`, but that is not the case for the example URL you have shown, because that contains the language first, so you would have to match `^en/catalog/…` here.

Comment: @CBroe Very nice response, it did not work just replacing `RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ $1 [QSA]` with `RewriteRule ^en/catalog/(.*)$ $1 [QSA]` . But that is certainly one step closer.

Comment: You want to keep the `/en/` after the rewrite, so your target URL should not be just $1 (because that contains what came _after_ en/catalog/ only), but `/en/$1` instead.

Comment: Can you give one example URL exactly as you want user to enter in his address bar, with real product name?

Comment: @DusanBajic yes, "example.com/en/high_pressure_washers". But that right now looks like this "example.com/en/catalog/high_pressure_washers".

Comment: But how will apache know if "high_pressure_washers" is categoryName or productName?

Comment: @DusanBajic Does it matter, when you want to remove them? Can't it just look after an occurrence of either "product" or "catalog", and then remove them?

Comment: Remove them from where if the user is entering "example.com/en/catalog/high_pressure_washers"? What page should apache show and how to determine that?

Comment: @DusanBajic If the user is entering "example.com/en/catalog/high_pressure_washers", then apache should show "example.com/en/high_pressure_washers". I was thinking it would determine that by just removing "/catalog/" when it appeared in the url.

Comment: Your request now sounds strange - you want user to type full long url, only to then redirect him to shorter one, while showing him the same page again. May I ask what is the rationale behind such request, perhaps it can be achieved in some other way (because rewrite rules can't do that - imagine if user after the redirect bookmarks that shorter url, then tries to open it sometime later, perhaps on another computer, we are back to the question how would apache determine whether to try to show product or category?

Comment: @DusanBajic, Well ofcourse it sounds strange. The user should type in "example.com" and automaticly it adds "/en". Then the user would click a hyperlink that would add "/catalog/high_pressure_washers". Catalog is there for my php to understand what type of request it is. But it doesn't look good for SEO or style. So I want to remove it afterwards. I misunderstood you when you  asked what a user would be typing in. I do appreciate you taking your time though.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/catalog/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

try this for all url

Comment: Hello, that didn't work for me sadly, nothing really happens. Does it take a while? Or should it work as soon as I click around the website as it refreshes?